# What are the disadvantage/consequences of moving updated column to separate table to prevent table lock on the original table?

Tags: sql-server, locking

I have a table p with a column points. There are a couple of million of records in the table and i need to regularly calculate and update the points for each row. This process takes a couple of minutes and it locks the table. I need to be able to insert and update records in p in the meanwhile. One solution I was thinking of is to create a second table and add a foreign key to p and the points column there. If this table is locked for a couple of minutes that's fine. Are here disadvantages/consequences that I should keep in mind with this solution?

Comment: Why is the table locked? Doesn't SQL Server do row-level locking?

Comment: If you insert a new record into p, I'm assuming you would need to add a points value that corresponds to that record into your lookup table for the points at the same time - correct?

Comment: The table is locked because  the number of rows/pages that are involved is so large that it is more efficient to lock the table

Comment: @JNK no that isn't necessary I can do that in the procedure that calculates the points.

Comment: @olle: wow, I didn't expect that from SQL Server (I'm mainly using Oracle and PostgreSQL and they will never lock an entire table because of the number of updated rows)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Really? The reason for doing so is because each lock takes memory and you don't want to be using GB of RAM just to store the locks for one update when you could trade it in for a single table lock (so it trades off concurrency vs resource usage). There is a trace flag in SQL Server to disable lock escalation but not advisable to use it.

Comment: @MartinSmith: In Oracle or PostgreSQL a lock does not need any memory because the lock is "attached" to the row. There is no lock manager (or whatever SQL Server uses)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Ah OK. I know nothing about the internals of either of those but that's the rationale for the SQL Server behaviour.

Comment: @MartinSmith - [More info for ya about locks in Oracle vs. SQL Server.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/872808/877069)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - See my previous comment too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I remember about this database from your earlier questions, I'd suggest you look at these alternatives to your approach:

- Consider [RCSI or Snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050.aspx). This will prevent your select queries being blocked during the update. Be mindful of the increased usage of tempdb this can generate but IIRC the nature of your database/data should mean this is small.
- Updating the points record in batches, rather than one almighty transaction for the entire table. See [How to Use Batch Size to Speed Mass Updates, Inserts and Deletes](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3141) for an old (but still relevant) approach.

Comment: I like option 2 for preventing lock escalation.  The hard part is finding just where SQL will escalate the lock to a full table lock.  SInce it can depend on the scenario, testing is the best way to yield the batch size.

Comment: I am reading up on both options.

Comment: I ended up going with the snapshot isolation level. The batched approach also worked but I got very random performance out of it and sometimes over 1000% worse.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how the points are calculated and, like others might, I don't have any insight into your earlier questions, but why would you need to constantly calculate the points values and store them? If you can calculate them based on other data, then storing the calculation seems redundant.

Again, not sure how points are calculated exactly, but if they are simple aggregations (e.g. counts), would it be possible to calculate the points in an indexed view? Then they are always up to date and you aren't going back and re-calculating the points for the entire table, even if only a subset of rows have changed since the last time you performed your calculations. Of course you will have to test the impact of the indexed view maintenance.

Comment: I'll have to look into that, the calculation is quite simple it's comparing the value of columns in p to another table and then adding a number of points depending on whether they are <, = or >. The calculated points will not change over time for a row thats been calculated but there will be billions of records and 100's of millions that will be calculated in one go.